# What media player do I need to play multiple music playlists through different output sources at the same time?

Tags: audio, music, media-player, audio-player

What media player do I need to play multiple music playlists through different output sources at the same time?

So one Bluetooth speaker playing nirvana. Headphones playing Led Zeppelin. And network speaker playing AC/DC. All on the same media player at the same time. What media player should I be using to accomplish this?

Comment: What platform…? You will likely need 3 apps whatever the OS, as o/ps are assigned by app, not stream.

Comment: @Tetsujin windows, and are you sure it’s not possible to modify the output source on a per instance basis?

Comment: You'd need the app's API to support it. I'm not very familiar with Win, I'm Mac, but even with pro-level routing on Mac you can't split one output to multiple streams. Look at Rogue Amoeba - https://rogueamoeba.com - Hijack, Loopback & SoundSource for the maximum you can do at consumer level [they're all Mac structures but you'll be able to see what is possible] Rogue Amoeba, btw, are the absolute pinnacle of this type of routing at consumer level. Pro level does have multiple inter-app routing, but it's highly specialised & expensive.